# Replace FrameLayout content from a custom view

Tags: java, android, android-framelayout

I'm currently working on creating a custom view which uses a xml layout file to render the view on the canvas. In this file I have a FrameLayout that is meant for dynamic content. I'm trying to change the content and in the custom view class with this method.

```
private void setFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    ((ActionBarActivity) getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_container, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

The problem with this is that I'm using the FragmentManager from the Activity this view is embedded in. Because of this the FragmentManager is referencing the Activity's layout file which does not contain my FrameLayout. I need this to be able to modify the content in the custom view's layout file so it can access the FrameLayout and change the content.

How can I go about accomplishing what I want? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

use callback pattern like [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). But define an interface in your view class and implement it in activity.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of the activity not being able to access content_container.